# how to test security of a login page and the whole website against hacking

Tags: php, security

how to test security of a login page, also security of the whole website against hacking.

Is there a trusted websites you dealt with before that do scans and give real results?

Comment: I think you want https://security.stackexchange.com/ but there are a number of tools (nessus, acunetix, etc.) that do automated security testing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way is to use free trials of working programs. One of those is [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/register-online-vulnerability-scanner/). You can also try fev manual injections, such as typing `name'` (with the single quote) to try to generate MYSQL error.